magento 2 error on enter home page
Hello after update to magento 2.4.7-p3
I have error.
I did remove and reinstall vendor. flush cache config compile. No think works.
Some have similiar problem ?
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\IdentifierInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(73): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'identifier', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(73): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'kernel', 'Magento\\PageCac...')
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\PageCac...', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\PageCac...', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\PageCac...', Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(73): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\PageCac...')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(173): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\PageCac...')
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(133): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Magento\\Framewo...', 'front-controlle...')
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('launch', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-application-performance-monitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor->aroundLaunch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#25 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#26 {main}```


Copy the di.xml file code from this
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/etc and replace the existing file in your website's app/etc/di.xml directory. After updating the file, run the following command:
php bin/magento c:f

